# Spot the same patterns in 2D arrays

Tags: java, arrays, oop, 2d

In one interview I was given a number of 2D arrays and asked to identify and count the same patterns of values occurring inside each of those arrays.

Patterns may be of any form. They may be squares, crosses, may have any form that repeats itself.

Graphically the data looked something like this:

```
ArrayOne
[0][1][1][0]
[0][1][1][0]

ArrayTwo
[1][1][0][0]
[0][1][0][0]
[0][1][0][0]

ArrayThree
[0][1]1][0]
[0][1][1][0]
[0][0][0][0]
[0][0][0][0]
```

And as output one would expect to see:

```
ArrayOne ArrayThree - "Two occurrencies"
ArrayTwo ArrayTwo - "One occurency"
```

As it stands, I do not see how we may iterate such arrays so as to retrieve their patterns. Of course, we could count the number of '1's in each array, but practically, it will have no use and will not answer the question.

Would much appreaciate constructive advice on how to achieve this in Java or any other widely used object-oriented language.

EDIT: The array contents were updated to remove the confusion that was present in the original post

Comment: I have to say I don't even know how you've come with that answer. It is not clear to me what are the requirements for something to count as an "occurence". I'd probably say that there is only one occurence.

Comment: "Patterns may be of any form." This is vague. Also if the pattern is occurring inside each array why do the output compares ArrayOne and ArrayThree? Does each array contain any type? A binary bit (0|1)? Strings, etc. What I understand by the question is that you need to compare 2 2D arrays (row by row). So ArrayOne and ArrayThree have common the 2 first rows (index [0][0-3] and [1][0-3])

Comment: why aren't there any patterns in Array two? I mean `0,0 - 0,0` looks like a pattern to me, Or is it only a pattern when there is at least one `1` in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They may be squares, crosses

Sounds to me like the definition of a "pattern" is a group of connected non-zero cells. Whether diagonals are considered connected is up for debate, but for squares and crosses they don't need to be.

Now collect all such patterns into a `Set` of 2D arrays. E.g. see [Find the number of islands](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-number-of-islands/) for how to find the patterns.

Example:

```
1 1 1 1 0
0 1 0 0 0
1 1 0 1 1
1 0 0 1 0
```

That contains 2 patterns:

```
1 1 1 1     1 1
0 1 0 0     1 0
1 1 0 0
1 0 0 0
```

Build a `Set` of patterns for each input array, then see if the sets have common patterns.

Or if you have many input arrays, build a `Map<Pattern, List<String>>`, where `Pattern` is a class wrapping a 2D array and implementing `equals()` and `hashCode()`, and the `String` is the name of the input array.

Comment: Special thanks for the clarity of your response. It is not for nothing that you have 90k of reputation!

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical question of any beginning to programming course.

Square pattern and cross pattern could be recognized with nested loops.

Start scanning the matrix from index 0,0.
At first [1] occurrence save indexes as starting indexes and move through the rest of the matrix in wanted direction (watch out do not go over the maximum size of the matrix).

Typical square/rectangle recognition pattern

```
x---->|
^     |
|     v
|<-----
```

You could also check if it is filled.
Similarly for cross pattern go straight line increasing both row and columns indexes.

Comment: Interesting starting point! can you complete your answer with an example on array one ? How would the algorithm go through that array and detect that there is a pattern?

Comment: In ArrayOne your program should scan first the row 0.
At index (0,0) finds 0. At index (0,1) finds 1, so it should save two variable (r_start=0, c_start=1) as starting points.

Now from r_start and c_start scan the row until a 0 is found and save the last 1 occurrence position (in the example at column 2) in the c_end variable.

At this point you have two corners of the shape (c_start and c_end), scan vertically each column (from r_start) and check you have the same number of ones.

Many approaches are possible, moving in a round fashion as I posted in the answer is another solution.

Comment: *"At this point you have two **corners** of the shape"* No you don't. The next row can be wider.

Comment: Right!
A flood-fill algorithm is the general solution to identify any connected area.